# JQuery Ajax petition is modifiying given URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to consume a API Rest aplication using JQuery Ajax. this is the code that I have:

```
  var res=$('#myForm').attr('action');
  console.log(res);
     $.ajax({
         url: res,
         success: function (data) {
               alert('success!!');
         },
         dataType: 'html'
  });
```

The console.log sentence is printing the url correctly, I just copied and pasted it into the browser and its correct, it's something like this:

```
http://localhost/myproject/public/2
```

But then, the request gives a 404 error, and the URL that is requesting is this one:

```
http://localhost/localhost/myproject/public/2
```

So, why it's attaching another `localhost` line to the url? I just don't understand!

Comment: what syntax is this: `res url=$('#myForm').attr('action');`?

Comment: You need to use something like this:`/myproject/public/2`

Comment: still not good - sort out `url` and `res` variables

Comment: @Igor edited, it was just a typing error

Comment: put "/" in front of `action` attribute of your form

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai ok, but I need a way to call a complete url

Comment: Do you tried @Igor solution ?

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai yes, but isnt woking.Because I'm using Laravel and I get the URL using `{{route('index',array('parameter1'=>'parameter'))}}` and puting "/" only gives me `/http://localhost/myproject/public/2`

Comment: You can use a little trick . Use this : `url: res.split('localhost')[1]`

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai yes, I thought the same. But then I don't know how it will behave in the production sever

Comment: Why don't ?  All you need is to get the part after `localhost`.

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai yes it works!! thank you very much! it was helpful (y)

Comment: @SrednyMCasanova, You're welcome , I will post this as an answer in order to help other people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is to get the part after `localhost`. For this, please use `split` method.

```
var res=$('#myForm').attr('action');
console.log(res);
$.ajax({
     url: res.split('localhost')[1],
     success: function (data) {
           alert('success!!');
     },
     dataType: 'html'
});
```